# Microsoft Vision API in Xamarin exception

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I was trying this tutorial in Xamarin:
Performing OCR for iOS, Android, and Windows with Microsoft Cognitive Services

But I get an: Exception of type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.ClientException' was thrown.'

It happens in the line:text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(photoStream);
I have looked at other post (none Xamarin) and they solved by setting the position of the stream to 0. I tried it but still get the same error.
The tutorial was written by Pierce Boggan.
Thanks for any help.

```
 OcrResults text;

            var client = new VisionServiceClient("my api key");

            using (var photoStream = photo.GetStream())
                text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(photoStream);
```

Comment: 1. Could you show some code of `GetStream()`? and 2. You mention you tried to set the stream position to 0 and it didn't help, could you show your code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It happens in the line:text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(photoStream); I have looked at other post (none Xamarin) and they solved by setting the position of the stream to 0. I tried it but still get the same error.

Different Areas have different Rest API Url, So in most cases, you need to set your `apiRoot` manually, which wasn't mentioned the tutorial, you posted. For detailed description, you can refer to [Obtain Subscription Keyps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtosubscribe).

To do that, you can obtain the API url in your subscription page:
[image]

And use the url to construct `VisionServiceClient` object:

```
OcrResults text;

    var client=new VisionServiceClient("Your API Key", "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0");

    using (var stream = photo.GetStream())
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.